# how to compile QVFB for embedded-linux-QT4.5 development on PC?

Tags: linux, embedded, qt4

How can I compile QVFB for embedded-linux-QT4.5 ?

Thanks,
  Sunny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Qt blog](http://thelins.se/learnqt/2009/06/an-embedded-linux-development-setup/) seems to be what you're after I think.